# Running a script as another user while knowing who ran the script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

In Linux, need to write a shell script which can be ran as other users (via doas permissions for this one script), but I need to know in the script who ran it originally. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [man page](https://man.openbsd.org/doas)

> By default, a new environment is created. The variables `HOME`, `LOGNAME`, `PATH`, `SHELL`, and `USER` and the umask(2) are set to values appropriate for the target user. **`DOAS_USER` is set to the name of the user executing `doas`**.

So use `$DOAS_USER` to get the original username.